# insert command with parameters error?

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I want to insert data from c# form into oracle database .... I use this line of code

```
com.CommandText = "insert into DEPTS VALUES (:code, :name)";
com.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(
    "code", OracleType.Int32,dept_cod_txt.Text, ParameterDirection.Input));
com.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(
    "name", OracleType.NVarChar, dept_name_txt.Text , ParameterDirection.Input));
com.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

it gives me some errors as below :
[image]

Comment: ok i change my image link

Comment: Don't use an image at all to show text. Copy and paste the actual text. Also, @GrantWinney, surely you can come up with something better than "enter image description here"?

Comment: @mohsen.d - Text is preferable for code and error messages, because it is more permanent (no worry of broken links) and unlike an image, it can be copied and pasted.

Comment: @Leigh , yes. I added the errors text at first place when he added a link to an external image. then when he added the image here , I removed my edit. you are right anyway.

Comment: @mohsen.d - Ah, I did not realize you were the one to "add" the text. Thanks, text is much better than a transient image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding wrong parameters.

you should use it [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kf9h5c82%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
new OracleParameter(
"parameterName", OracleType, length, "db column name");
```

suppose your table fields are **code** and **name**. then

```
var codeParameter = new OracleParameter(
"code", OracleType.Int32, 4, "code");

codeParameter.Value = Convert.ToInt32(dept_cod_txt.Text);

var nameParameter = new OracleParameter(
"name", OracleType.NVarchar, 20, "name");

nameParameter.Value = dept_name_txt.Text;

com.Parameters.Add(codeParameter);
com.Parameters.Add(nameParameter);
```

the one with **ParameterDirection** parameter has a different [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7tyyhcs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

you can find a list of all possible signatures [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: can you give me more detail please ... what js parameterName,length and db column name?

Comment: thank you mohsen.d my problem is solved ... but if you can i need to do the same thing for delete,update,select query can you help me?? share the same code for delete,update and select query